# php replace string not before defined char

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace sub string but just when is not just "=" right of them.
Eg.  replace "foo" net before "=" with "bar" (ignore whitespace)

```
1) foo=foo    =>   foo=bar
2) foo = foo  =>   foo=bar    (whitespace before "=")
3) (foo)=foo  =>   (bar)=bar  ("=" is not just after "foo")
```

Do you know any simple preg_replace?
I tried something like

```
/(foo)([\S^=]*)/x' etc
```

but it matches all "foo" => bar=bar

Comment: [`\s*=\s*foo` -> `=bar`](https://regex101.com/r/jO8pZ0/1)? If there are only 2 members separated with `=`, you can rely on the `explode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\s*(=?)\s*foo(?!\s*=)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1bar`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/29

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using an explode:

```
$replacement = "bar";
$parts = explode('=', $string);
$parts[0] = $eplacement;
$string = implode('=', $parts);
```